# Page View Controller Data Source

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am new for Obj-C and on the stage of learning it. Just saw that code and trying to get that. However, in the first code starting with -(UIViewController *) pageViewController.... is so complicated for me.

Anyone who can explain that step by step?

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have a UIPageViewController. It is currently showing a page at index K within all N pages. The UIPageViewController needs to know what page comes before the current page that is being shown (at index K) and the page after the current page.

Here's how that looks:

```
//Called on the data source. Returns the UIViewController before the 
//current one (viewController) within the UIPageViewController (pageViewController)
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    //gets the index of the page currently showing
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    //Checks that it's not the first page and that it's
    //actually a part of the UIPageViewController
    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        //If it is, then there is no page before it.
        return nil;
    }

    //otherwise, lets go back one index
    index--;
    //and then this is the UIViewController before it
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

For the second method, it's doing the same thing, but is trying to get the page after. Again, iOS needs to know these things so, at a high level, it can quickly present that page when the user changes pages.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    //gets the index of the current page being shown
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    //if it's not found, then there isn't a page after it
    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    //go to the next index
    index++;
    //if we're at the end of the pages
    if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
        //there's no page after it
        return nil;
    }
    //otherwise, return the next UIViewController
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: How about the code starting with -(UIViewController *) pageViewController... ending like (UIViewController *)viewController?  
There is something like (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController. What those codes mean exactly? This was also a part that I could not get

Comment: That's the name of the method being called every time your app needs to know that information. The file with those methods, the data source, has those called when the UIPageViewController needs to know what pages come before and after. It passes the UIPageViewController that needs to know, and the UIViewController it's currently on and it's supposed to return a UIViewController (the one before or after depending on the method)